# Linkedin to broadcast

Tags: internet, gwibber

How add Linkedin to broadcast?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The broadcast tool (called [Gwibber](http://gwibber.com/)) needs to support this. Here's the [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/gwibber/+bug/520845) if you want to follow along in its progress.